# How to find specific value using generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, iterable

I created a generator that returns a tuple, for instance the name of an item and the price.

```
output = ('apple',$2)
```

I want to find the tuple when the price is the maximum, out of all outputs of the generator.

I know how to get the maximum of the second item when the tuple is not an output of the generator, but I don't know when the generator needs to be looped.

Should I append the looped outcomes and create a super list first? For instance, `[('apple',$2),('pear',$1) ... ]`

Comment: $2 is illegal python .. me thinks - either it is a string or a number w/o the $ sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` accepts any iterable. A generator is an iterable. You can supply a custom `key` function so that `max` considers only the 1st index:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# generator expression below can also be a generator function
gen = (i for i in (('apple', 2), ('pear', 1)))

res = max(gen, key=itemgetter(1))  # ('apple', 2)
```

Comment: That works if `tup[1]` is an `int`, otherwise a custom function to cast as int is needed

Comment: @Dalvenjia, Agreed, in that case, you can use `lambda x: int(x[1])` (if it's a string).

Comment: or `lambda x: int(x[1].strip('$'))` if the amount is in dollars as stated in the question